# Reachability:currentReachabilityStatus returns ReachableViaWifi when Wifi is turned off

Tags: ios, reachability

As per the title, I've turned off Wifi on my iPhone and it has an LTE connection, yet when I call Reachability:currentReachabilityStatus it returns ReachableViaWifi. Code is:

```
in the init:
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(reachabilityChange:)
                                                     name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        _reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:[[MYURLs defaultServerBaseURL] host]];
        [_reachability startNotifier];
         NetworkStatus status = [_reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
        // here status is NotReachable
        ....


- (void) reachabilityChange: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NetworkStatus status = [self.reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
   // here status is ReachableViaWifi
}
```

Why is the status ReachableViaWifi when Wifi is disabled?

I'm turning the wifi off before running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug in iOS8 Beta as the same code produces expected results in iOS7.

Comment: Original question did not specify it occurred using a beta release.

Comment: I am experiencing the same in 10.3.3 alpha

Answer (score 0):

In `reachabilityChange:`, instead of calling `[self.reachability currentReachabilityStatus]`, look at the object of the notification.

```
- (void) reachabilityChange: (NSNotification*) notification {
    Reachability *reach = [notification object];
    NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
}
```

Comment: Putting your code exactly and running it still reports ReachableViaWifi

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. Grabbing the latest Reachability classes from Apple fixed it, though.

[Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)